# Error autostarting Linux service after reboot if condition is met: "Path in condition not absolute, ignoring"

Tags: linux, systemd, autostart

I have a service named `MyService` that needs to auto-start a NodeJS process only if "Configured!" can be found inside of a configuration file. The `MyService.service` file contains the following in the `Service` section:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "if grep -q 'Configured!' /path/to/configuration/file.conf; then /usr/bin/node /path/to/node/process.js; fi"
```

However, the problem is that the NodeJS process does not auto-start. In fact, when I look in `journalctl`, I see the following error message:

> Path in condition not absolute, ignoring: "/path/to/configuration/file.conf"

**How can I please change `ExecStart` to successfully auto-start the NodeJS process when the condition has been met?** This is very puzzling because when I run the `ExecStart` command on the command line, it works correctly. Also, the path to the configuration file is an absolute path.

(Also, please note that since this machine is running an old version of systemd, I am not able to use `ExecCondition`.)

Comment: It's a long shot but did you try full path of `grep` binary? it may have not complete `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Great idea! But unfortunately that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with double quotes in :

```
"/path/to/configuration/file.conf"
```

which makes systemd think it's not a absolute path.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? The error message uses double quotes, but the actual ExecStart command is `ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "if grep -q 'Configured!' /path/to/configuration/file.conf; then /usr/bin/node /path/to/node/process.js; fi"`. The double quotes are intended for the /usr/bin/sh -c option, which passes the bash command as a string.

Comment: If you know, can you please suggest how the above `ExecStart` command can be changed in order for it to correctly perform the auto-restart if the condition is met? Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste a minimal example of `MyService.service` ? The problem may not be in ExecStart.